# Is It Possible to Replace the Value of the_content() on a Custom Post Type Single Page?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I'm trying to use the Passster (password-protection) plugin to protect a single page for a custom post type. But the protection is only triggered for the_content() and I'm not using that on the template. It's primarily ACF fields and custom HTML.

Is there a way to override the value of the_content() on this template with my custom PHP code?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

[`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) includes a filter that you can use to change the content to whatever you want, but be careful (check priorities on the filter) as that filter is likely how the plugin is protecting the page.